# elasticsearch: applying an additional boost on a given field for a given value

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have a Symfony 2.7.6 application using the [FOSElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle).

I have 2 types of search:

1. One without keyword, in this case only filters are applied and all documents scores are 1 (sometimes with a random order), in this case the main query is:

   ```
   $query = new Elastica\Query\MatchAll();
   ```
2. One with keyword, same filters are applied and the match is run again a list of fields, (one with a different boost). And the results are stored by score. The main query is now:

   ```
   $match = new Elastica\Query\MultiMatch();
   $match->setQuery($keyword);
   $match->setOperator('AND');
   $match->setFields([
       'field1^30',
       'field2',
       'field3',
       'field4',
       '_all'
   ]);
   ```

Those 2 search are working well.

Now for both search I want a dynamic boost to be applied for a given field value. Let's say: `if field5 == 'value' then add boost 15`, (15 is just an example, we will make tests to see what additional boost value has to be chosen) the value used here is not the keyword, it is another parameter.

I tried with a `FunctionScore` and with `Boosting` queries but without success. Any hint with a very simple elasticsearch query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "blabla",
          "operator": "AND",
          "fields": [
            "field1^30",
            "field2",
            "field3",
            "field4",
            "_all"
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "field5": "some_value"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 15
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll give a try today. :)

Comment: Works well, I was messing when nesting my queries. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. No problem :-).